# Rails 5: ajax post request not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm currently trying to add a form to my homepage. The survey calculates the needed impressions based on the user input.

The problem is that when I pass the value `impressions` for example `200` to ajax, it sends a `POST` request back to the form, but there I have `@impressions = params[:impressions]` which is `nil`.

Since `@impressions = params[:impressions]` already exists with the `GET` request. The `POST` request isn`t even showing up in the console.

Ajax code:

```
  $.ajax({
    data: 'impressions=' + impressions,
    dataType: 'script',
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/pages/home"
  });
```

Routes:

```
  root to: 'pages#home'
  post '/pages/home' => 'pages#home'
```

PagesController home:

```
  protect_from_forgery :except => [:home]

  def home
    @impressions = params[:impressions]
  end
```

What would be the right soultion? Probably I should set `@impressions = 0` and change the ajax request from `POST` to `PUT` ?

Comment: `Since @impressions = params[:impressions] already exists with the GET request. The POST request isn`t even showing up in the console.` I don't understand that, show the server log when you do that ajax request. Do you have a .js view for that route? when do you call that ajax request from your view?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe format your Ajax request as Json?

```
  $.ajax({
    data: {impressions: impressions}
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/pages/home"
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below method.

```
$.ajax('/pages/home', {
  type: "POST",
  data: 'impressions=' + impressions,
  dataType: 'script'
})
```

Hope this helps!!